# ListView not refreshing after updating object in the list

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I've an `ArrayList` containing `Card`s. I'm trying to edit a `Card`s tag in the ArrayList and after editingit I want the ListView to refresh, so the user can see the updated `Card`, with the new tag.

I'm using [cardslib](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib) for my Cards. And I'm using [Android TagView Lib](https://github.com/mcharmas/android-tagview) to tag my cards.

Here's the XML for the `Card`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/colorBorder"
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/card_base_empty_height"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle" />

<TextView
    (...) />

<TextView
    (...) />

<TextView
    (...) />

<TextView
    (...) />

<pl.charmas.android.tagview.TagView
    android:id="@+id/tags_view"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_below="@id/card_main_inner_simple_total_contacts"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:textSize="12sp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here's when I try to edit and update the list view:

```
private final OnClickCardHeaderPopupMenuListener popupMenuListener = new OnClickCardHeaderPopupMenuListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMenuItemClick(BaseCard baseCard, MenuItem menuItem) {

        final String backupId = baseCard.getId();

        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_restore:
                BackupsIntentService.restoreCloudBackup(getActivity(), backupId);
                Log.d(TAG, "Going to update the card");
                setCurrentTask(backupId, "Restoring...", "");
                break;

            case R.id.action_download:
                BackupsIntentService.downloadCloudBackup(getActivity(), backupId);
                break;

            case R.id.action_delete:
                BackupsIntentService.removeCloudBackup(getActivity(), backupId); 
                break;
        }               
    }
};
```

And here's the `setCurrentTask` method, where I update and refresh the list:

```
private void setCurrentTask(final String backupId, final String currentTaskDescription, final String separator)
{
    int pos = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i<cloudBackupCardList.size(); i++)
    {
        BackupCard backupCard = (BackupCard) cloudBackupCardList.get(i);
        if(backupCard.getId().equals(backupId))
        {
            pos = i;
            Log.d(TAG, "Found the card at position: " + i + " updating it now");
            TagView.Tag[] tags = {new TagView.Tag(currentTaskDescription, Color.BLUE)};
            backupCard.setCurrentTaskDescription(tags, separator);
        }
    }

    if(pos == -1)
        return;

    BackupCard backupCard = (BackupCard) cloudBackupCardList.get(pos);
    Log.d(TAG, "There should be: " + currentTaskDescription + " but found: " + backupCard.getCurrentTaskDescription() + " Thread: " + Thread.currentThread()
            .getName());

    cardListView.setAdapter(new RemoteCardArrayMultiChoiceAdapter(getActivity(), cloudBackupCardList));
//      remoteCardArrayMultiChoiceAdapter.remove(remoteCardArrayMultiChoiceAdapter.getItem(pos));
//      remoteCardArrayMultiChoiceAdapter.insert(backupCard, pos);
//      
////        remoteCardArrayMultiChoiceAdapter.clear();
////        remoteCardArrayMultiChoiceAdapter.addAll(cloudBackupCardList);
//      remoteCardArrayMultiChoiceAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
//      cardListView.refreshDrawableState();
}
```

I've tried all those (the commented ones) different methods and the list is still not updated.

Here's my logcat output:

```
07-07 15:12:59.644: D/CardCloudBackupsFragment(24311): Going to update the card
07-07 15:12:59.644: D/CardCloudBackupsFragment(24311): Found the card at position: 8 updating it now
07-07 15:12:59.656: D/CardCloudBackupsFragment(24311): There should be: Restoring... but found: RESTORING... ThreaD: main
```

As you can see from the logcat, the object is updated but in the listview, on my terminal, it is not. Which leads me to conclude that the listview is not updated/refreshed. (Dont mind the all upper case letters in `Restoring`, it's expected.)

**////////////////////// EDIT ////////////////////////////////**

Here is my `setupInnerViewElements` method as requested in the comments box.

```
@Override
public void setupInnerViewElements(ViewGroup parent, View view) {

    //Retrieve elements
    titleTextView = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.card_main_inner_simple_title);
    subTitleTextView = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.card_main_inner_simple_sub_title);
    TextView descriptionTextView = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.card_main_inner_simple_description);
    TextView totalContactsTextView = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.card_main_inner_simple_total_contacts);
    tagView = (TagView) parent.findViewById(R.id.tags_view);

    if(isLocal)
    {
        if (titleTextView != null)
            titleTextView.setText(TIMESTAMP_TXT + titleCard); // 1st

        if (subTitleTextView != null)
            subTitleTextView.setText(CONTACTS_COUNT_TXT + subTitleCard); // 2nd

        if(descriptionTextView != null)
            descriptionTextView.setText(RESTORE_COUNT_TXT + description); // 3rd

        if(tagView != null)
        {
            TagView.Tag[] tags = {new TagView.Tag("Wow", Color.TRANSPARENT)};
            tagView.setTags( tags, "" );
        }

        return;
    }

    if (titleTextView != null)
        titleTextView.setText(TIMESTAMP_TXT + titleCard); // 1st

    if (subTitleTextView != null)
        subTitleTextView.setText(PHONE_BRAND_TXT + subTitleCard); // 2nd

    if(descriptionTextView != null)
        descriptionTextView.setText(PHONE_MODEL_TXT + description); // 3rd

    if(totalContactsTextView != null)
        totalContactsTextView.setText(CONTACTS_COUNT_TXT + contactsNumber); // 4th

    if(tagView != null)
    {
        TagView.Tag[] tags = {new TagView.Tag("Wow", Color.TRANSPARENT)};
        tagView.setTags( tags, "" );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your setupInnerViewElements ?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I've edited the question and added the code you asked for. Please check the edited question.

Comment: In method you are changing only the currentTaskDescription value. But in your setupInnerViewElements you never call getCurrentTaskDescription() method. Am I wrong?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti yes you are right. I've found the problem. It was just a simple thing and I made it a big problem. The Android TagView Lib already does update the cardView so there is no need for me to update it, so when I tried to update it again I was reseting the status. I'll post an answer and close this question. Thanks for your time and help! Great library you have there :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace below Line:

```
cardListView.setAdapter(new RemoteCardArrayMultiChoiceAdapter(getActivity(), cloudBackupCardList));
```

with

```
RemoteCardArrayMultiChoiceAdapter adapter=new RemoteCardArrayMultiChoiceAdapter(getActivity(), cloudBackupCardList));

cardListView.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Thats it...

Comment: Just did that but the list doesn't show the cards updated. It does seems the list is somehow updated because when I scroll down the list and select a card to edit then the phone shows the list from the beginning, starting at the very top. But still the card shows the outdated information

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a no problem at all, it was as simply as setting the tag and the TagsLibrary would take care of updating the CardView. I just didn't know this so I was trying to refresh the listview.

So I simply have this method on my card class:

```
public void setCurrentTaskDescription(TagView.Tag[] tags, String separator)
{
    tagView.setTags(tags, separator);
}
```

and then on my listener I just do this:

```
switch ( menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_restore:
                BackupsIntentService.restoreCloudBackup(getActivity(), backupId);
                EventBus.getDefault().post(new 
                setCurrentTask(backupCard, "Restoring...", "");
                break;
}

private void setCurrentTask(final BackupCard backupCard, final String currentTaskDescription, final String separator)
{
    TagView.Tag[] tags = {new TagView.Tag(currentTaskDescription, Color.GREEN)};
    backupCard.setCurrentTaskDescription(tags, separator);
}
```

No need to refresh the list!
I was trying to make a thunderstorm inside a glass of water. Lesson learned.